# How do I use conditional formatting to highlight invalid values in In LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Edit: version:

```
Version: 7.3.2.2 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 49f2b1bff42cfccbd8f788c8dc32c1c309559be0
CPU threads: 10; OS: Mac OS X 12.2.1; UI render: default; VCL: osx
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Calc: threaded
```

[image: conditional formatting dialog]

I want that V value in N20 to have a red background. Formula for the range is `NOT(OR(EXACT($B$3, "X"), ISBLANK($B$3))))))` which reads as:

- if the value is not either of

  - an exact match for "X"
  - blank
- then return true

I've tested this formula in a separate cell and it works as expected. But when I apply the conditional formatting to the range of cells nothing happens. What's wrong with the formula?

To be clear what I'm expecting is all the values in the screenshot **except N20** to have no formatting. N20 should have a red background.

Answer (score 1):

Too many parentheses.

1. Create (or find) a Style that sets red background.
2. With N3 as first selected cell, and N20 included in the selection...
   `NOT(OR(N3="X", N3=""))`
3. Select the style, to actually get red cells.

*Excel: The only difference is that you do not need a Style, instead you define the "style" directly.*

[image]

---

```
Version: 6.4.7.2
Build ID: 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.4
CPU threads: 12; OS: Linux 5.13; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3; 
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI-Language: en-US
Calc: threaded
```

Comment: That formula isn't highlighting the "V" in the screenshot. Used `NOT(OR($N$3="X", $N$3=""))`.

Comment: Remove ALL the `$`  - as you have them, the formula will only affect N3, nothing else

Comment: Tried that too. It's working for empty cells but not the V. https://imgur.com/6qK0A39

Comment: Check the image that I inserted.

Comment: I'm using the "Error" built in style. I don't think defining a custom style is the issue here.

Comment: Wild, apparently it works if I use a custom style but doesn't work if I use the built-in style.

Comment: Changed the style to Error in the image. Maybe there is something wrong with your styles?! LibreOffice 6.4.7.2 here.

Comment: I'm using the current version, 7.3

Comment: Old version lingering due to the fact that personal Calc-sheets are much simpler than those I use in Excel, at work.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is for 6.4, I have 7.3.

I got this to work like so:

1. Remove all conditional formatting for the range.
2. Place a test value in a cell that is in the middle of your range. For me I put a few here and there.
3. Apply conditional formatting to the first cell in the range, formula `NOT(OR(B3="", B3="X"))` (adapt as needed), style is "Error" (built in style)
4. Use the format painter to drag the formatting from the first cell to the rest of the range.

Result:

[image: conditional formatting image]